# GridX Tree Expando REST call (large dataset) with Async datastore

Tags: json, rest, asynchronous, dojo, dojo.gridx

I am using GridX and I am looking to create a grid with 'expandoes' similar to http://oria.github.io/gridx/demos/tree.html and the example 'All expandoes in one column, async store'

I want to populate the grid using a JSON that has been returned from a REST call.

However, the JSON is too big (50MB) so I want to break it down.

I want to be able to populate the grid with the minimum amount of data that the user needs to see, then when the click on an expando, another REST call is made and the row's children are returned and added to the grid.

```
require([
'dojo/parser',
'dojo/_base/Deferred',
'gridx/tests/support/data/TreeColumnarTestData',
'gridx/tests/support/data/TreeNestedTestData',
'gridx/tests/support/stores/ItemFileWriteStore',
'gridx/allModules',
'gridx/Grid',
'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync',
'gridx/core/model/cache/Async',
'dijit/ProgressBar',
'dijit/form/NumberTextBox',
'dojo/domReady!'
], function(parser, Deferred, dataSource, nestedDataSource, storeFactory, modules){

store = storeFactory({
    dataSource: dataSource, 
    maxLevel: 4,
    maxChildrenCount: 10
});
store.hasChildren = function(id, item){
    return item && store.getValues(item, 'children').length;
};
store.getChildren = function(item){
    return store.getValues(item, 'children');
};

storeAsync = storeFactory({
    isAsync: true,
    dataSource: dataSource, 
    maxLevel: 4,
    maxChildrenCount: 10
});
storeAsync.hasChildren = function(id, item){
    return item && storeAsync.getValues(item, 'children').length;
};
storeAsync.getChildren = function(item){
    var d = new Deferred();
    console.log('getChildren: ', storeAsync.getIdentity(item));
    setTimeout(function(){
        var children = storeAsync.getValues(item, 'children');
        d.callback(children);
    }, 1000);
    return d;
};

storeNested = storeFactory({
    dataSource: nestedDataSource, 
    maxLevel: 4,
    maxChildrenCount: 10
});
storeNested.hasChildren = function(id, item){
    return item && storeNested.getValues(item, 'children').length;
};
storeNested.getChildren = function(item){
    var d = new Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var children = storeNested.getValues(item, 'children');
        d.callback(children);
    }, 1000);
    return d;
};

var progressDecorator = function(){
    return [
        "<div data-dojo-type='dijit.ProgressBar' data-dojo-props='maximum: 10000' ",
        "class='gridxHasGridCellValue' style='width: 100%;'></div>"
    ].join('');
};

layout1 = [
    //Anything except natual number (1, 2, 3...) means all levels are expanded in this column.
    {id: 'number', name: 'number', field: 'number',
        expandLevel: 'all',
        width: '200px',
        widgetsInCell: true,
        decorator: progressDecorator,
        editable: true,
        editor: 'dijit/form/NumberTextBox'
    },
    {id: 'id', name: 'id', field: 'id'},
    {id: 'string', name: 'string', field: 'string'},
    {id: 'date', name: 'date', field: 'date'},
    {id: 'time', name: 'time', field: 'time'},
    {id: 'bool', name: 'bool', field: 'bool'}
];
layout2 = [
    //Expandable column defaults to the first one, if no expandLevel provided.
    {id: 'id', name: 'id', field: 'id'},
    {id: 'number', name: 'number', field: 'number',
        widgetsInCell: true,
        decorator: progressDecorator
    },
    {id: 'string', name: 'string', field: 'string'},
    {id: 'date', name: 'date', field: 'date'},
    {id: 'time', name: 'time', field: 'time'},
    {id: 'bool', name: 'bool', field: 'bool'}
];
layout3 = [
    {id: 'number', name: 'number', field: 'number'},
    {id: 'string', name: 'string', field: 'string'},
    {id: 'date', name: 'date', field: 'date'},
    {id: 'time', name: 'time', field: 'time'},
    {id: 'bool', name: 'bool', field: 'bool'},
    {id: 'id', name: 'id', field: 'id'}
];
layout4 = [
    {id: 'id', name: 'id', field: 'id'},
    {id: 'number', name: 'number *', field: 'number', expandLevel: 1},
    {id: 'string', name: 'string *', field: 'string', expandLevel: 2},
    {id: 'date', name: 'date', field: 'date'},
    {id: 'time', name: 'time *', field: 'time', expandLevel: 3},
    {id: 'bool', name: 'bool', field: 'bool'}
];


mods = [
    modules.Tree,
    modules.Pagination,
    modules.PaginationBar,
    modules.ColumnResizer,
    // modules.SelectRow,
    modules.ExtendedSelectRow,
    modules.CellWidget,
    modules.Edit,
    modules.IndirectSelectColumn,
    modules.SingleSort,
    modules.VirtualVScroller
];

parser.parse();
});

    <div id='grid2' jsid='grid2' data-dojo-type='gridx.Grid' data-dojo-props='
    cacheClass: "gridx/core/model/cache/Async",
    store: storeAsync,
    structure: layout2,
    paginationBarSizes: [1, 2, 0],
    modules: mods
'></div>
```

Here is the code that is used in the example. I've removed the non-async stores and the nested stores from the code. I'm not sure how to create:

A. the original data store. What type does it have to be? dojo.store.memory? or should it be a jsonrest store?

B. I assume that I need to make changes to the getChildren function and add in something here to be responsible for fetching the additional data (the children of the expanded row)?

Can I just call back the children and will they be added to the async store automatically.

Has anyone done something like this before? Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into dojo's [JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) and see if that helps.
Your getChildren method would look like this:

```
store.getChildren = function(item) {
    return this.query(item.childId);
};
```